# Audio/Video Doing weird things, with new Connections

Tags: windows-8, usb, audio, video

I have a Logitech G430 USB headset, and whenever I seem to plug in a USB with things on it, or with nothing on it, I will get the Ping of a new connection then ALL audio shuts off. Not only that, if I attempt to run a video when this happens, the video seems to move at a few frames per second. I have tried many "fixes" but to no avail. The only way I get my audio back is to completely restart my PC.

Also, if I boot my PC with said USBs already plugged in then I have no issues. If I attempt to plug them in while Windows 8 is running I get the audio glitch 90% of the time.

I would love some information on what it could be and what I should do to attempt to fix the problem. I have run many anti-Malware programs in attempts to fix it, as well as scanned for possible viruses and such, squeaky clean with CCleaner as well.

As per requests of some comments,

I have tried drivers for Motherboard, Headset, and pretty much EVERYTHING else on my computer. i have attempted Male-ware as a what else could i try method and virus scanning for the same problems. The only reason i tried malware is because i couldn't think of other things.

As for What i mean by USBs with noting and other things on it. Regardless of what i plug into a USB slot on my PC whether it be a Printer, Thumb-drive(empty or not), headset, microphone, webcam, external hard drive (empty or not). The problem will occur. and has occurred withe each of the above mentioned devices.

Comment: Adding the fixes you have tried would help.  What makes you think malware?  Have you assured you have latest drivers for mainboard and the headset?

Comment: can you please clarify what a "USB with things on it or nothing on it" is? I expect you mean a flash drive, but I personally have a USB printer, a usb mouse, a usb audio (guitar) interface, 2 usb gamepads, etc. Does this problem happen when hot-plugging *any* USB device?

Comment: Edited for clarifaction Dave M and horatio